# json_decode removes zero at first char in string numbers

Tags: php, json

When i pass a phone number (that is a string) with leading zero number to `json_decode`, It removes the first zero char and converts it to a float number.

```
$string = '09178882356'; //dynamic value
echo json_decode($string); //9178882356 will be echo
```

How to prevent it ?

**Edit**:
Florent provided a solution to use something like:

```
echo json_decode('"'.$string.'"');
```

It works, But if `$string` is a real JSON string, Then it fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are decoding a number.
You should change your code to:

```
echo json_decode('"09178882356"');
```

**Edit:**

> It works, But if `$string` is a real JSON string, then it fails.

The problem is that you don't really know your object type. Maybe you should stop sending real JSON string to this function or wrap your number with quotes outside your function.

You can try something like this:

```
if (is_number($str)) {
    $str = '"'.$str.'"';
}

echo json_decode($str);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following function will take into account multiple leading zeros and convert to string if leading zeros are encountered:

```
    function check_number($num){
        $re = '/[0]+/m';

        preg_match_all($re, $num, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0); 

        $leading_zero = $matches[0][0] ?? false;
        $length = 0;

        if( $leading_zero !== false){
            $length = strlen($num);

            $test = "%'.0{$length}d\n";

            return sprintf("%'.0{$length}d\n",$num);                
        }

        return $num;
    }
```

```
$one = '07';
$one = check_number($one) // returns '07' string with json_encode and JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK flag

$two = '007';
$two = check_number($two) // returns '007' string with json_encode and JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK flag

$num = 7;
$num = check_number($num) // returns 7 int with json_encode and JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK flag
```